# Reduce raster resolution and determine pixel inclusion based on % pixel overlap

Tags: raster, spatial-analyst, idl

I'm trying to reduce the resolution of a raster from 1m to 50m using a pixel aggregation (average) method, but I need to set a threshold for inclusion (e.g. 75% of the 1m pixels must fall within the 50m pixel in order for the 50m to be included in the new raster).  How to go about doing that? I've looked into the resize tool in ENVI, the congrid tool in IDL, gdalwarp in GDAL, and the aggregate tool in ArcGIS, and haven't figured out a solution.  Any thoughts?

Comment: If you align the 50m grid to the corner of the 1m grid, presumably it will align at every square.